# Difference in mlr output between R and excel

Tags: r, excel, regression, multiple-regression

I'm attempting to perform a multiple regression in R using data that originally came from excel. I perform the regression in R using the lm() function, but when I perform the same regression on the same set of variables using the Regression feature in the Solver add-in in Excel, I get a materially different result - very different R^2 value, and different coefficients on my independent variables. Does anyone know of a reason for this problem?

I'll clarify my steps here:
Create my data in excel, arranged where each row is an event and each column is a variable. Save a copy of the excel file as a tab delimited text file.

```
frame1<-read.table("Data_file.txt")
x1<-frame1[,2]
x2<-frame1[,3]
x3<-frame1[,4]
x4<-frame1[,5]
x5<-frame1[,6]
x6<-frame1[,7]
x7<-frame1[,8]
x8<-frame1[,9]
y<-frame1[,8]
lm1<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6)
summary(lm1)
```

I've run `as.numeric(x1)` on all the x* and y, to check that R is importing each as a number, which it does (returns TRUE).

In excel, I open the solver add-in, select "Regression", select the y and x ranges, and view the outputs. I've manually viewed the vectors in R to make sure the values are the same, and I tried rounding the values in my excel file to make sure that rounding when they are saved into a text file or imported into R isn't the problem - it doesn't fix it.

Anyone with any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: R output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = lnAssdFCexpanded ~ UNRATE + Housing + SP500 + Outstanding + 
    CPI + GDP + libor12 + ACR)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.069644 -0.017137  0.004542  0.014124  0.050276 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  5.403e-01  2.096e+00   0.258  0.79798   
x1       3.509e-03  5.179e-02   0.068  0.94635   
x2     -4.282e-03  4.328e-03  -0.989  0.32893   
x3       -4.812e-05  2.515e-04  -0.191  0.84930   
x4  2.788e-04  3.102e-04   0.899  0.37459   
x5         -1.859e-03  7.254e-03  -0.256  0.79917   
x6          4.769e-06  1.206e-04   0.040  0.96866   
x7     -1.619e-01  1.042e-01  -1.554  0.12871   
x8          1.510e-02  5.427e-03   2.783  0.00844 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02888 on 37 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.324, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1778 
F-statistic: 2.217 on 8 and 37 DF,  p-value: 0.04849
```

Excel output:

```
SUMMARY OUTPUT              

Regression Statistics               
Multiple R  0.6585439           
R Square    0.433680069         
Adjusted R Square   0.311232516         
Standard Error  0.026435745         
Observations    46          

ANOVA               
    df  SS  MS  F
Regression  8   0.019801242 0.002475155 3.541761833
Residual    37  0.025857398 0.000698849 
Total   45  0.04565864      

    Coefficients    Standard Error  t Stat  P-value
Intercept   -0.540575382    1.95242173  -0.276874291    0.783417585
X Variable 1    0.00497459  0.047237193 0.105310868 0.916697997
X Variable 2    -0.000348463    0.004154182 -0.083882529    0.933602042
X Variable 3    -0.000140051    0.000229284 -0.610818478    0.545054069
X Variable 4    0.000111365 0.000280844 0.396536602 0.693987066
X Variable 5    -0.002129205    0.006640379 -0.3206451  0.750283376
X Variable 6    5.79194E-05 0.000111833 0.51790939  0.607604647
X Variable 7    -0.16469405 0.093923869 -1.753484509    0.087800642
X Variable 8    0.034494338 0.008515322 4.050855618 0.000250969
```

Comment: have you checked what's in frame1? do you have a header row in `"Data_file.txt"`?

Comment: Please post your R, and Excel output. Along with a `dput(head(frame1))` to your post.

Comment: @mtoto I do have a header row and column in my text data file. When I extract the data from the frame to vectors and view it, however, the data aligns with what I expect (i.e. the first entry for x1 is my expected value of x1 at the first observation).

Comment: @Vlo I'm editing the outputs into the initial post.

Comment: Tested both Excel 2016 and R. The Solver addin for Excel did not have regression (the Analysis ToolPak addin does). I fit lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, mtcars) in both. R's Multiple R-squared equals Excel's R Square (0.767). Adjusted R-squares equal in both (0.743). Looks like Excel's Multiple R is just sqrt(R Square). Based on this, I would guess that you did not fit the same model in each. (Plus other problems: the intercept in the R model you have is positive but the Excel one is negative. And that the variables in the call of the summary don't match the parameter names below.)

Comment: As a double check, do `sapply(frame1, class)`. The specified models are likely different because none of the coefficient estimates are remotely similar. If your data is public domain, then perhaps you can try posting/linking the full dataset.